# How to delete the last 5 lines of a file

Tags: perl, file, printing, lines

I have several commands printing text to a file using perl. During these `print` commands I have an if statement which should delete the last 5 lines of the file I am currently writing to if the statement is true. The number of lines to delete will always be 5.

```
if ($exists == 0) {
  print(OUTPUT ???) # this should remove the last 5 lines
}
```

Comment: check out this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/345513/how-can-i-delete-the-last-n-lines-of-a-file

Comment: From the Stack Overflow and official Perl FAQ: [How do I change, delete, or insert a line in a file, or append to the beginning of a file in Perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322140/how-do-i-change-delete-or-insert-a-line-in-a-file-or-append-to-the-beginning)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Tie::File](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Tie%3a%3aFile):

```
use Tie::File;
tie my @array, 'Tie::File', filename or die $!;

if ($exists == 0) {
    $#array -= 5;
}
```

You can use the same array when printing, but use `push` instead:

```
push @array, "line of text";
```

Comment: As soon as I read the title I thought "Tie::File FTW!" You beat me to it. +1

Answer (score 3):

```
$ tac file | perl -ne 'print unless 1 .. 5' | tac > file.tailchopped
```

Comment: @TLP: `head: unknown option -- -` and `usage: head [-count | -n count] [file ...]`.  That’s not POSIX compatible.

Comment: @TLP So what? That’s not POSIX. It’s not standard. It’s a prosaic local variant. I have at least 3 systems where it fails miserably. You should not expect other people to run non-standard software. People who live in the Linux glasshouse don’t know what the real world outside is like.

Comment: I'd take `head -n -5` over `tac` in a portability contest any day.

Comment: @socketpocket Just alias *tac* to `perl -e 'print reverse <>'` — I always do. :) Honestly, I probably had that for decades before *tac* (1) started shipping. Heck, I had a *tac* before Perl, for goodness’ sake!

Comment: @tchrist I think you're being somewhat negative here. The point is that it is better to see if `head` can be used on your system, than it is to reverse the file, print, and reverse it again.

Comment: @TLP: if you are going to suggest standard Unix tools, provide a version that doesn't use long options (as socket puppet has done). Long options are a GNU extension, and not portable.

Answer (score 1):

Only obvious ways I can think of:

1. Lock file, [scan](http://search.cpan.org/~ingy/IO-All-0.44/lib/IO/All.pod#Reading_Backwards) [backwards](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3a%3aReadBackwards) to find a position and use
   [truncate](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/truncate.html).
2. Don't print to the file directly, go through a buffer
   that's at least 5 lines long, and trim the buffer.
3. Print a marker that means "ignore the last five lines". 
   Process all your files before reading them with a buffer as in #2

All are pretty fiddly, but that's the nature of flat files I'm afraid.

HTH

Comment: Not that these are "bad" suggestions, but Tie::File has the magic built-in.

Comment: @Joel Berger, Not it doesn't. Tie::File reads the file from the start, so it would definitely be much slower than (1) for large files. Not to mention all the memory it would use up from creating an index of every line in the file.

Comment: @ikegami, you are right about #1 being faster (for large files). All I had actually meant was that Tie::File would do most of the work, not that it would be more efficient

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, print the whole file except last 5 lines:

```
open($fh, "<", $filename) or die "can't open $filename for reading: $!";
open($fh_new, ">", "$filename.new") or die "can't open $filename.new: $!";
my $index = 0; # So we can loop over the buffer
my @buffer;
my $counter = 0;
while (<$fh>) {
    if ($counter++ >= 5) {
        print $fh_new $buffer[$index];
    }
    $buffer[$index++] = $_;
    $index = 0 if 5 == $index;
}
close $fh;
close $fh_new;
use File::Copy;
move("$filename.new", $filename) or die "Can not copy $filename.new to $filename: $!";
```

Comment: This is #2 from Richard Huxton's answer

Comment: `$index = 0 if 5 == $index` can also be written `$index %= 5`, assuming increments of one.

Comment: Those are very strange open calls. `open` returns an undefined true value on success and zero on failure - neither of which are useful as file handles. `$file` is where the filehandle should be, but it is undeclared and you use the same variable twice. Also `$filename.new` requires double-quotes around it or it won't compile.

Comment: @Borodin - brain hiccups - didn't have caffeine yet. You're absolutely right.

Answer (score 1):

[File::ReadBackwards](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3a%3aReadBackwards)+[`truncate`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/truncate.html) is the fastest for large files, and probably as fast as anything else for short files.

```
use File::ReadBackwards qw( );

my $bfh = File::ReadBackwards->new($qfn)
   or die("Can't read \"$qfn\": $!\n");

$bfh->readline() or last for 1..5;

my $fh = $bfh->get_handle();
truncate($qfn, tell($fh))
   or die $!;
```

Tie::File is the slowest, and uses a large amount of memory. Avoid that solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this:

```
open FILE, "<", 'filename';
if ($exists == 0){
 @lines = <FILE>;
 $newLastLine = $#lines - 5;   
 @print = @lines[0 .. $newLastLine];
 print "@print";
}
```

or even shortened:

```
open FILE, "<", 'filename';
@lines = <FILE>;
if ($exists == 0){
 print "@lines[0 .. $#lines-5]";
}
```